# Find difference between two maps

Tags: scala

I found several approaches to find the difference of the keys sets between two maps. however, I want to compare complete key->values.

I have a two maps setup as `Map[String, Map[String, String]]`

So if I have two maps

```
var source = Map(
  "one" -> Map("a" -> "bbb", "b" -> "qww"),
  "two" -> Map("b" -> "ccc")
)

var target = Map(
  "one" -> Map("a" -> "bbb", "b" -> "qqq", "c" -> "ccc"),
  "two" -> Map("b" -> "ccc")
)
```

I want to do something like `source - target`

To get a final output of

```
 Map("one" -> Map("b" -> "qww")
```

I only care about ensuring all of `source` matches with `target` (So in the example, `target("one")("c")` is irrelevant).  I am wondering if there is some nice one line function I can do to accomplish this, if not, I can always fall back to loop through it all and comparing by hand.

edit code update -

```
var differences = new ListBuffer[(String, String)]()
source.foreach{
  case (db, tableMap) =>
    tableMap.foreach{
      case (table, createTable) =>
        if(createTable != target(db)(table)){
          differences.append((db, table))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Then maybe you should fall back to loops and present a piece of code that produces exactly the desired output on arbitrary examples, not on a single example with three elements. It would help to unambiguously determine whether the "optimized" versions produce the same result. In this particular example, it is not clear what is supposed to happen if `target("one")` does not contain keys `"a"` and `"b"` at all. What should happen if `target` does not contain `"one"` in the first place?

Comment: If `target` does not contain `one` then it should add all of `one` to the output.

Comment: Here is a simple objective, I want to ensure all of the source is in and equal to the target, but I do not care if the target has items not in the source.

Comment: So, you sort-of want `src + (trg - src) == trg`, where `+` means "override everything in the left map by the stuff in the right map", and `-` is your "difference" operation? No, wait, that can't be true... I don't understand what to do in the case that the difference is actually "negative". You "do not care if the target has items not in the source" - OK. But I still don't understand why you would want to add anything if some keys are present in `src` but lack in `target`.

Comment: Yeah, exactly..

Comment: So `src + (trg - src) == trg` is the logic I am looking for in the end.  I want a final map where items in the source are either different or not present in target.

Comment: The problem with `+` in my previous comment is that it can only *add* elements. The problem with `src.filterNot(difference.contains)` is that it only *removes* elements. What's supposed to happen in the situations where you have to both add ("green lines in git-diff") and remove ("red lines in git diff") stuff from `src`?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking, however, I edited the main post with a simple loop example of what I am trying to accomplish.  (It only keeps tracks of the keys, though I want the `Map[String, Map[String, String]]` portion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your requirement, `source diff target` (as lists) would work well.  By traversing the `diff` list from the two outer Maps using `foldLeft`, applying `diff` again for each key against the inner Maps between source and target would generate the wanted net inner Maps:

```
val source = Map(
  "one" -> Map("a" -> "bbb", "b" -> "qww"),
  "two" -> Map("b" -> "ccc"),
  "three" -> Map("c" -> "xxx")
)

val target = Map(
  "one" -> Map("a" -> "bbb", "b" -> "qqq", "c" -> "ccc"),
  "two" -> Map("b" -> "ccc"),
  "four" -> Map("d" -> "yyy")
)

(source.toList diff target.toList).
  foldLeft( Map[String, Map[String,String]]() ){ (acc, x) =>
    val corrTargMap = target.getOrElse(x._1, Map[String, String]())
    val mapDiff = (x._2.toList diff corrTargMap.toList).toMap
    acc + (x._1 -> mapDiff)
  }
// res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Map[String,String]] =
//   Map(one -> Map(b -> qww), three -> Map(c -> xxx))
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test the performance on this and hopefully it is better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

This works ( No `toList` or `toMap` etc conversions) :

```
s.map{case (x,y)=>(x,y.filter(p=>t.getOrElse(x,Map()).forall(_!=p)))}.filter(_._2!=Map())
```

**In Scala REPL:**

```
scala> val s = Map(
     |   "one" -> Map("a" -> "bbb", "b" -> "qww"),
     |   "two" -> Map("b" -> "ccc"),
     |   "three" -> Map("c" -> "xxx")
     | )
s: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]] = Map(one -> Map(a -> bbb, b ->
 qww), two -> Map(b -> ccc), three -> Map(c -> xxx))

scala> val t = Map(
     |   "one" -> Map("a" -> "bbb", "b" -> "qqq", "c" -> "ccc"),
     |   "two" -> Map("b" -> "ccc"),
     |   "four" -> Map("d" -> "yyy")
     | )
t: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]] = Map(one -> Map(a -> bbb, b ->
 qqq, c -> ccc), two -> Map(b -> ccc), four -> Map(d -> yyy))

scala> s.map{case (x,y)=>(x,y.filter(p=>t.getOrElse(x,Map()).forall(_!=p)))}.filter(_._2!=Map())
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]] = Map(one -> Map(b -> qww), three
 -> Map(c -> xxx))
```